# Problems using curl to post form variables to a Flask application with special characters- Error 405

Tags: php, curl, flask, urlencode

I'm trying to write a PHP script to log into a Flask website.  It is using curl to submit a login form, store the login token in a cookie, and then allow the web server to download information from the secure site.  However, it appears there is an issue where the required special character in the password is not being transmitted properly.  If I remove the special character, the call is successful, but it returns an invalid password error.  If I include the special character, I get a 405 error from the Flask server.  I've tried base64 encoding the password, urlencoding it, manually putting the escape characters in the password string, and have had no success.  Is there a particular mechanism I need to use to ensure the password is delivered properly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm running out of ideas.

```
<?
//username and password of account
$username = "user@website.com";
$password = "n6EsBbz.AARyK7GEV";

//login form action url
$url="https://target-site.com/login/dashboard"; 
$postinfo = "username=".$username."&password=".$password."&state=&rememberMe=on";

$cookie_file_path = "cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
// extra headers
$headers[] = "Accept: */*";
$headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";

// basic curl options for all requests
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: The exact error I get is: 
No resource method found for POST, return 405 with Allow header

Comment: You should probably percent-encode the password. And you can remove the CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST" which might cause problems for you when following redirects.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel!  I had tried the percent encoding before, but removing the CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST did the trick!  You are the man!

Comment: Great, converted my comment to an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`, "POST" which might cause problems when following redirects, as the response code in a redirect may tell the client to switch to another method for the followed-to request while the `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` string then overrides that.